# Python 3 serial, problem reading characters

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, uart

Good day.
When sending numeric characters from the Terminal from a computer to RPI through 2 USB - TLL adapters, an incorrect character is received. If I just send from the RPI through the adapter in a circle and get a symbol on the RPI, then the result is the same.
Baud rate 9600, 8 bits, no parity, stop bit 1.
The program is simple in Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
 
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, timeout=2, writeTimeout=1)

while 1:
    er = ser.read(1)
    print (er) 

ser.close()
```

I enter in terminal 1 and get g. I enter in terminal 2 and get 3. I enter in terminal 7 and get d.

Didn't find a solution on the internet. When sending a character from RPI to the terminal, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I tried switching from Python 3 to the less finicky Python 2, but the result was the same. It became clear that the question was in the gland. I changed the USB - TTL adapter to another one and it worked!